# TypeScript, jQuery DataTables passing Settings

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, visual-studio-2015, datatable

Ok, I'm new to TypeScript and wanted to try it in my current Project. I have to say it's great so far there's just one thing i cannot get working. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and installed the necessary packages via NuGet like jQuery and jQuery DataTables and also some Bootstrap parts. The point is, i cannot pass the settings correctly to my DataTable function like I could with normal JS.

The DataTables Method is defined as follows:

```
(method) JQuery.DataTable(param?: DataTables.Settings): DataTables.DataTable
```

My current Code looks like this:

```
_tblInitialAccount = $('#tblInitialAccount').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        filter: true,
        ajax: _sAjaxUrl,
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: -1,
                sortable: false,
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    if (data == null) {
                        return '<button type="button" class="btn-link" onclick="OnBtnAddRowClicked(event)"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>';
                    } else {
                        return '<button type="button" class="btn-link" onclick="OnEditRowClicked($(this).parents(\'tr\'))"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></button>&nbsp;' +
                                '<button type="button" class="btn-link" onclick= "OnSaveRowClicked($(this).parents(\'tr\'))" > <i class="material-icons" > save < /i></button > ';
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```

The Errors i get are:

> Argument of type '{ processing: boolean; serverSide: boolean; filter: boolean; ajax: any; columnDefs: { targets: nu...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Settings'.
>     Property 'oFeatures' is missing in type '{ processing: boolean; serverSide: boolean; filter: boolean; ajax: any; columnDefs: { targets: nu...'.
>
> Build: Argument of type '{ processing: boolean; serverSide: boolean; filter: boolean; ajax: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Settings'.

Clearly there is some issue with casting the passed parameter to the type 'Settings' or something similar but directives like `as DataTables.Settings` don't work. There isn't any Tutorial or example Code that covers this combination. Most of the examples are in combination with angular or PHP which neither of them are used in my project.

Comment: Answered in this Post already
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733182/how-does-visual-studio-2015-resolve-typescript-typings-d-ts-files