# How to use JQuery.Datatable extensions with Typescript?: Not Assignable to parameter of type 'Settings'

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, datatables, typescript-typings

I saw [this solution for a similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733182/how-does-visual-studio-2015-resolve-typescript-typings-d-ts-files) problem but can find no evidence of the older JQuery.Datatable type file in my project so I'm at a loss where my problem is coming from. Rather than with Nuget, I'm using npm. I can't figure out if there is another way I should reference the type or if there is different syntax for the parameters for the `.DataTable({responsive: true})` call.

```
Error   TS2345  (TS) Argument of type '{ responsive: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Settings'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'responsive' does not exist in type 'Settings'.
```

package.json:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.8",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.16",
    "@types/knockout": "^3.4.46",
    "@types/knockout.mapping": "^2.0.30",
    "@types/knockout.validation": "0.0.35",
    "@types/requirejs": "^2.1.31",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "datatables-bootstrap3-plugin": "0.5.0",
    "datatables-epresponsive": "0.0.3",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.16",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.16",
```

fooViewModel.ts

```
    import * as ko from "knockout"
    import * as $ from "jquery"
    import "datatables.net";
    import "datatables-epresponsive";
    import "datatables.net-dt"; 


export class FooViewModel {

        constructor() {
            super();
            this.instantiateLocalObjects();

            if (this.containerIsLoaded()) {
                this.onPageIsActive();

                $("#employeeTable").DataTable({ responsive: true } ); 
            }
        }
```

> Update: It seems that the problem is specific to trying to use
>   JQuery.Datatable Extensions (e.g. responsive and select). For example
>   this throws no errors:

```
$("#employeeTable").DataTable({
                "paging": false,
                "ordering": false,
                "info": false } );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem turns out that there are in fact type files for each of the extensions *and* I had installed `datatables-epresponsive` thinking it was `datatables-responsive`.

I had to run:

```
npm install --save datatables.responsive.typings
npm install datatables.net-responsive
```

I was also trying to use select and needed this:

```
npm install --save @types/datatables.net-select
```

Comment: Worked partially, still getting alerts `row is not a Method...` but solves ~90% of problems